# does c50 algorithm works only on categorical datasets?

Tags: r

I found a sample code with `iris` data set in R language. 
I want to use the same code but with other data set(heart disease dataset) which has only numerical values.will that work?

Comment: Yes it will. But it's better for you to proceed further understanding Decision Tree's basics. Also give a try with CART!

Comment: The code which i found was.

data(iris)
table(iris$Species)
set.seed(9850)
g<-runif(nrow(iris))
irisr<-iris[order(g),]
C5.0(irisr[1:100,-5]). The following is my code which is giving me an error. C5.0(dats[1:100,-1])
Error in is.factor(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default.
 how can solve this?

Comment: Minor improvement of the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data doesn't contain missing values. If values are missing, Compiler will throw an error, while model building stage. So, if some data points are missing, probably you should try for imputing them.

Also Make sure your output Variable/class variable is Categorical in nature.
Also, if its binary classification problem and labels are 0,1 
make sure you encode those 0's and 1's to proper text labels and then convert them into factor's.

Example for encoding numbers into categorical's

```
    data$class  <-  ifelse(data$class==0,"not_found","found")
    data$class <- as.factor(data$class,levels=c("found","not_found))
```